# Is there an equivalent to JsonSchemaResolver.GetSchema when using JSchemaResolver?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I have some older code that use the `JsonSchemaResolver` class and the `GetSchema` method, but according to the documentation those are now obsolete. Therefore I want to update my code to use the new API, but I can't seem to find the corresponding way of getting a resolved schema with the `JSchemaResolver` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really an equivalent method with `JSchemaResolver`.

While `JsonSchemaResolver` was just an id/value dictionary of schemas, `JSchemaResolver` is designed to resolve schemas from external resources. Its main method `GetSchemaResource` returns a `Stream` which is then loaded internally.

Something like `JsonSchemaResolver` was removed because it couldn't handle complex situations like circular schema relationships.